# Emergency SOS settings

Tags: android, actions-on-google, google-apps, google-app-maker

Q1. Is there a way to programmatically set the settings of Emergency SOS menu?
Such as setting the countdown time and turn off "play warning sound". You can do both manually but wondering if i can set it programmatically at an app.

Q2. Is there a way to skip the calling part of Emergency SOS? Current flow is countdown -> call -> countdown -> sms, want it to just send an sms right away.

Thank you for your assistance in advance

Comment: It sounds like you may just want to create your own app with similar capabilites.